Gradient over halftone pattern - Illustrator
little question: I have this black and transparent halftone pattern swatch I've been using in Illustrator.

Now I would like to apply this gradient to the black parts of the pattern, so I can make it darker at the edges and lighter at the center of the stroke, giving it a more dynamic look.

Is there a way to do it? I've been trying to do it with a clipping mask, but for whatever reason it's not working.
Sorry for the giganting images and I hope my question is clear. Lmk if I have to reformulate it.
P.S.: I have been able to sort of recreate the desired effect in Photoshop, but it's still not quite there and working this way I had to completely sacrifice the ability to edit the gradient (eg. its thickness), which I sort of still need.


is your second image using a gradient stroke?

Yes, it's a path with a basic brush applied and a radial gradient with "apply gradient across stroke"

So, I finally found a way to create the effect I wanted to a t.

Create your path.

Now apply a stroke with the halftone pattern swatch. (I personally use a '40% Rough Halftone' from RetroSupply, a very good texture they provide as a free sample, but the basic halftone pattern at Swatch Libraries Menu > Patterns > Basic Graphics > Basic Graphics Dots works as well, although, in my opinion it's not as nice).

Duplicate your path. Windows > Layers > Duplicate.

Change the stroke of the Duplicated Path to a Basic stroke with Radial Gradient and Gradient applied across the stroke.

Put the Halftone Path on top of the Gradient Path.

With the Halftone Path selected Rasterize the path. (Object > Rasterize...), then Image trace it (Object > Image Trace > Make)

Go to Windows > Image Trace and under Advanced select Ignore White, then do Object > Image Trace > Expand, finish this process doing Object > Compound Path > Make.

Select the newly created Compound Path and the Path with Gradient, then do Object > Clipping Mask > Make


You're finally done: You have an halftone pattern in whatever shape you want with transparent background clipped over a path with a gradient stroke you can edit any time.

It's a bit of a complex process, but I really like the effect, skipping any step in my experience results in funny shapes that are not what I intended. If anybody out there has a quicker way to do this please post anytime. I might create a script to do this faster as I better learn my way around Illustrator scripting.

Impressive, well done!

@Pitchoune thanks!!! It was quite the hassle. Now if somebody upvotes the answer I might even get the teacher badge :)

Here's a partial workaround which will be sufficient if you have only one background color.

Create your path
Apply a stroke with the halftone pattern swatch. Just in case, the swatch is present by default in the Swatches pannel, by clicking on Swatch Libraries Menu > Patterns > Basic Graphics > Basic Graphics Dots
Go to the Window > Appearance menu while having the shape selected. This allows you to add a second stroke on top of the first one
Create the stroke with a symmetric half-transparent half-white (or whatever color your background is) gradient and the same width as the other stroke. It is possible to click-and-drag the first stroke on the + button to duplicate it and directly have the correct thickness/stroke parameters like round caps.
Still in the Appearance menu, click on the Opacity button of this second stroke and change its blend mode to Lighten. This mimic the transparency effect of the halftone at the middle of the stroke.

An example is shown here, with a colored background on the right to show the trick:

Although this is not perfect due to the transparent part of the halftone pattern being colored, I hope this will lead you to a solution!

Yeah thanks! knowing more ways to do the thing is always useful! at least I can think through different ways to streamline the process before I import the file in photoshop and use the clipping mask there if I can't find a pure Illustrator solution.
Unfortunately you got the issue 100%: I do need the transparent part of the halftone pattern to stay transparent.

Finally figured it out, thought you might want a heads up to see how I did and exchange ideas.

for what its worth, from a semi novice- I made a brush for a chrome tube effect. It looks same as your gradient but, its chrome coloured. I just fraw, and use the chrome tube brush.

sounds good! but would you know how to combine that with a halftone pattern so that the crome effect only shows over the black(or colored) areas of the halftone? That's my real problem, that's the thing I could only do importing the file in photoshop and using the clipping mask there. I tried to do it with the clipping mask in illustrator, but it was giving me the area of the effect all wrong.

If you can put photos of your chrome tube in your answer I'd love to see it anyway/hear more about it.
